# Performance difference between a wild card import and the required class import

Tags: java, import, performance

What is the complexity in terms of performance between

```
java.io.*
```

and

```
java.io.File
```

PS.

I know that the first one will include every file in `java.io.*` and the next one only the selected class file.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

At runtime 0.

Both generate the same byte code

Comment: How about compile time? Java will need to search among the classes that are being use...

Comment: The answer to that is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7128687/139985 :-)

Answer (score 54):

Imports are resolved to fully qualified names at compile time.  There is no runtime performance difference.  If you look at the generated bytecodes in the two cases, they will be identical.

There *might* be a *small* compile time overhead in using one or the other form, but it is likely to be *so small* that nobody should notice it, let alone care about it.

> I know that the first one will include every file in java.io.* and the next one only the selected class file.

Not exactly.  What a star import does is to make all of the class names available *to the compiler*.  The actual classes themselves are not "included" ... in the sense of the C or C++ programming languages.

---

The real reasons that many people use explicit imports rather than wildcard imports are:

- Explicit imports clearly document what external classes a class is directly using, provided that you don't leave redundant imports in your code.
- Explicit imports avoid problems with name collisions arising when you import two packages that contain classes with the same (simple) class name.
- Explicit imports avoid fragility problems where someone adds a new class to some package that you have wildcard imported.  This can lead to new compilation errors (in code that previously used to compile) due to a name collision; see the previous bullet point.

Modern IDEs have accelerators, code elision and other features that can help you keep your imports under control when you use explicit imports.  So the "brevity" advantage of using star imports is diminished.

Answer (score 12):

There is no performance impact on runtime, there might be impact on compilation time:
http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm031.shtml

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no affect on run time performance. Because `import` statement is a compiler directive and is not converted to the byte code. As stated by @ Stephen C there is only a compile time overhead.

Answer (score 5):

There is no performance difference between a specific import
and a wildcard import declaration.

> The information for the classes in imported package is not read in at
>   compile time or run time unless the class is used in the program. The
>   import statement simply tells the compiler where to locate the
>   classes. There is no performance difference between a specific import
>   and a wildcard import declaration.

(Liang, Daniel Y. "Introduction to Computers, Programs and Java." Introduction to Java Programming. Comprehensive Version. 9th ed. N.p.: Pearson, n.d. 24. Print.)

Answer (score 0):

In jsp if you are having 'Undefined Variables in EL' then wild card import statement should be avoided.  Wild card import will have huge impact over runtime performance (Due to “Static Field and Method Reference” processing).

Answer (score -1):

There is no performance difference between them.