# Implications importing java packages with wildcard

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is using a wild card with a Java import statement bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad)
>   [Performance difference between a wild card import and the required class import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128348/performance-difference-between-a-wild-card-import-and-the-required-class-import)

What are the implications of importing a java package using `.*` versus specifying a package explicitly.  For example,

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
```

instead of

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
```

Are there penalties at compile time or run time when using wild card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely no effect on run time.

Wildcard imports are probably marginally slower at compile-time, but I wouldn't think you'd need to care.