# Difference between import java.util.* and java.util.XXXX

Tags: java, import, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance difference between a wild card import and the required class import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128348/performance-difference-between-a-wild-card-import-and-the-required-class-import)
>   [Implications importing java packages with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062199/implications-importing-java-packages-with-wildcard)

My QA leader set up a checkstyle rule that `java.util.*` can not appear in the source code, use `java.util.XXX` instead. For example , you can only write:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
// ... may be thousands import statement here
```

but not allowed:

```
import java.util.*;
```

If anyone do not follow the rule, QA team will not do the integration test. He told me that the style of `import java.util.XXX` is more clear than `import java.util.*`, and makes JVM run faster. Is it true ？

Comment: It is slightly clearer but it **definitely** does **not** make the JVM run faster (imports are resolved at compile time, not at runtime).

Comment: your question mark is stunning...

Comment: *"makes JVM run faster"*  That part is incorrect.  It affects only the compiler.  By run-time, the classes are individually and explicitly identified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include `java.util.*`, you're including *all of the classes* in the `java.util` package.

When including `java.util.classname`, you're only including the specified class in the `java.util` package.

Using `java.util.*` will not slow down the JVM because imports are handled at compile time, not runtime.