# java import statement overheads to memory or JVM

Tags: java, memory-management

Do the import statements acquire any space on the heap or JVM ? Lets say I have a class which where many java packages are imported, which are not used. So when this class is instantiated, will these unwanted import of packages create any overhead on heap or stack or JVM ?

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128348/performance-difference-between-a-wild-card-import-and-the-required-class-import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, imports are just used by the compiler to resolve class names.